# Mapnik upsampled raster isn't smooth

Tags: mapnik, resampling, smoothing

I'm using Mapnik to show a map with hillshading. It works well when displaying it up to my tiff's native resolution and a little bit above, for instance at zoom 13 (dataset is SRTM30):

[image]

But then if I continue to zoom in, the hillshade isn't smooth anymore and looks like vector polygons, like on this screenshot at zoom 16:

[image]

I'm currently using bicubic scaling but I tried every single other option without seeing much improvement. Upscaling my raw image at the same resolution with Photoshop works perfectly, with smooth fading.

Is there a way to improve this result? I tried to add agg-stack-blur without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was mod_tile's output format, which is 8 bits PNG. Recompiling mod_tile to make it generate 32 bits PNGS solves the problem (but multiplies the tiles size by 3).

More details [here](https://github.com/openstreetmap/mod_tile/issues/64).